# Python dictionary restructure

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I have a list of nested dictionaries in a specific format as input. I need to restructure the dictionary in a different format as mentioned in the output. The numeric value present in the input's name needs to be treated as a parent key. Can anyone help me with this?

```
input = [
    {
        "A": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "1234",
                    "name": "109 - Apple",
                    "description": "Apple"
                },
                {
                    "description": "Mango",
                    "id": "5678",
                    "name": "17892 - Mango"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "B": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "4563",
                    "name": "109 - Apple",
                    "description": "Apple"
                },
                {
                    "description": "Mango",
                    "id": "9767",
                    "name": "17892 - Mango"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

After restructuring the input data should be come in below format

```
output = [
    {
        "109": [
            {
                "A": {
                    "id": "1234",
                    "name": "109 - Apple",
                    "description": "Apple"
                }
            },
            {
                "B": {
                    "id": "4563",
                    "name": "109 - Apple",
                    "description": "Apple"
                }
            }
        ],
        "17892": [
            {
                "A": {
                    "description": "Mango",
                    "id": "5678",
                    "name": "17892 - Mango"
                }
            },
            {
                "B": {
                    "description": "Mango",
                    "id": "9767",
                    "name": "17892 - Mango"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    {
        "A": {
            "values": [
                {"id": "1234", "name": "109 - Apple", "description": "Apple"},
                {"description": "Mango", "id": "5678", "name": "17892 - Mango"},
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "B": {
            "values": [
                {"id": "4563", "name": "109 - Apple", "description": "Apple"},
                {"description": "Mango", "id": "9767", "name": "17892 - Mango"},
            ]
        }
    },
]

out = {}
for d1 in lst:
    for k, v in d1.items():
        for d2 in v["values"]:
            out.setdefault(d2["name"].split()[0].strip(), []).append((k, d2))

for k, v in out.items():
    v[:] = [{vv[0]: vv[1]} for vv in v]

out = [out]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "109": [
            {"A": {"id": "1234", "name": "109 - Apple", "description": "Apple"}},
            {"B": {"id": "4563", "name": "109 - Apple", "description": "Apple"}},
        ],
        "17892": [
            {"A": {"description": "Mango", "id": "5678", "name": "17892 - Mango"}},
            {"B": {"description": "Mango", "id": "9767", "name": "17892 - Mango"}},
        ],
    }
]
```